# FileNotFoundError even though the file exists

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, file-not-found, python-3.9

So, I was making a game using Python 3 and the Ursina game engine and keep getting this error while trying to load the file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    from src.menu import *
  File "/home/mysteriousk/Desktop/moni moni moni/src/menu.py", line 4, in <module>
    with open('../assets/database/database.json','r') as E:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '../assets/database/database.json'
```

The file I am executing is `main.py and the file I am importing is in the folder src and is named` menu.py`. The code for loading my file:

```
with open('../assets/database/database.json','r') as E:
    stuffs = json.load(E)
```

The file obviously exists in the directory assets/database. Please let me know whats wrong any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is assets folder inside or outside src folder?

Comment: @harundemir918 it is outside of the src folder.

Comment: Can you try this: `./../assets/database/database.json`

Comment: @harundemir918 didnt work .-.

Comment: @MysteriousK - Could you please provide your project file structure?